# Load category collection by category id in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have get the overall category collection by calling this sample code in xml file.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

This will return the overall category collection but i want to get the specific category collection by category id .I don't want to use object manager or want to create a custom module

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
  namespace Mage\Mohit\Block;
  class Category extends 
 \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  {
    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context 
      $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface 
     $categoryRepository,
       array $data = []
        ) {
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
     }

    /* $categoryId as category id */
     public function getCategoryById($categoryId){
         try {
  return $category = $this->categoryRepository- 
    >get($categoryId);
    } catch 
   (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) 
     {
        return ['response' => 'Category Not Found'];
    }
   }
 }
```

Call From template file, Pass argument as Category id,

`$categoryId = 5; // category id
  $getCategory = $block->getCategoryById($categoryId);
  echo $getCategory->getName();echo "<br>";
  echo $getCategory->getUrlKey();echo "<br>";
  echo $getCategory->getIsActive();echo "<br>";
  echo "<pre>";print_r($getCategory->getData());`

And more refer this link :-

**https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-category-collection-by-category-id-in-magento-2/**

Any query let me know..

Thanks.